# Specify global scope in Swift

Tags: swift, scope, namespaces

Can you specify the global/module namespace in Swift?

This code:

```
func foo(i: Int) { print("global foo", i) }

class Bar {
  func foo() { foo(5) }
}
```

leads to the error `Argument passed to call that takes no arguments`. I've seen it said elsewhere that `MyProject.foo(5)` or `Swift.foo(5)` or maybe `MyModule.foo(5)` might work, but in Swift 2.1.1 they do not seem to.

EDIT: It sounds like from the answers that have come in that `MyProject.foo(5)` works for other people. Anyone have any ideas why it might not in my project?

Comment: Curious. Why should you be able to pass 5 to a function that takes no arguments?

Comment: The function at the global scope is the one that takes arguments. You sound just like the compiler.

Comment: When I looked at it, I for some reason didn't see a foo() that took arguments. But now I do.

Comment: That was easier the solve than the compiler error, at least!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh. The problem was that I had a class with the same name as my project, so `MyProject.foo` resolved to the class name rather than the global scope.

I don't know if there's a better workaround than a `let` alias for the global function at the global scope, or @Kiet Nguyen's suggestion to move globals into a namespace. But at least that explains it.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can use your project's name, for instance "`MyProject`", then you could call the global function like this:

```
class Bar {
  func foo() { MyProject.foo(5) }
}
```

But I suggest to keep your global function in a class like this:

```
class GlobalFunctions {
   static func foo(i: Int) { print("global foo", i) }
}

class Bar {
  func foo() { GlobalFunctions.foo(5) }
}
```

This way, your code is more readable.

Comment: I mentioned that I tried this in the question. But there must be something specific wrong with my project.

Comment: @Grumdrig Which Xcode are you using? Maybe you should install the latest one!

Comment: 7.2, which I'm assuming is up to date? At least App Store doesn't care to update it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can specify the global scope by prefacing the symbol name with the project name as shown in Xcode. For example, if your project name is "myapp", then you may invoke your global function foo(_:Int) as `myapp.foo(5)`.

Comment: Your question indicates you tried using the project name and it still didn't work, but I had no problem when I tried it in Xcode 7.2 and Swift 2.1.1. Sorry but I don't know what the cause of the problem may be.

Comment: I did. I guess it must be something specific to my setup. I can't imagine what.